# cached_network_image gives error when no image is found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: widget.geocache.image,
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Text("lol"),
),
```

And when it finds the cached image its ok but when my wifi is of and it doesn't find a cachedimage it throws an error. I just want to see if the image is cached and so yes show image but if no then print a text